# How can the sensitivity of capacitive touch sensors be limited?

Tags: sensors, pins, adafruit, input

I have an [Adafruit circuit playground classic](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3000), and the touch-pads are so very sensitive. From a centimeter away, they trigger.  I would be happy to just have regular inputs, or to have the sensitivity reduced. How can I do this?

To clarify, here is my code:

```
//keyboard control for TuxKart power Glove
#include <Adafruit_CircuitPlayground.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <Mouse.h>
// set pin numbers for the five buttons:
const int Fire = 6;
const int Nitro = 9;
const int Eagle = 10;
const int _Esc = 12;

bool slideSwitch;

void setup() { // initialize the buttons' inputs:
  pinMode(Fire, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(Nitro, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(Eagle, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(_Esc, INPUT_PULLUP);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize mouse control:
  //Mouse.begin();
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if (!CircuitPlayground.slideSwitch()) {
    return;
  }

  // use the pushbuttons to control the keyboard:
  if (!digitalRead(Fire) == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.write('KEY_SPACE');
    Serial.println("F");
  }
  if (!digitalRead(Nitro) == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.write('n');
    Serial.println("U");
  }
  if (!digitalRead(Eagle) == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.write(0xB2);
    Serial.println("N");
  }
  if (!digitalRead(_Esc) == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.write(0xB1);
    Serial.println("K");
  }
delay(200);
}
```

This code or any other, where capacitive touch sensitivity has not been specified, yields pins having extreme sensitivity. I have read the comments, that say the MCU doesn't feature this natively. If that were true, how would the pins remain sensitive?

My solution to this is to set sensitivity so low, that it is negligible. If capacitive touch sensing is not specified, why am I getting that functionality? Why would this code give me capacitive touch sensing? 
Ideally, I would disable the touch sensing somehow, or have the pins simply behave normally, like any other Arduino based device that doesn't have touch sense. But what I have guessed, (shown in code) doesn't work. If there is a more explicit way to specify that IO pins should act as normal pins, without capacitive touch sensing, I would surely like to know.

Comment: Please edit your question to include part numbers and links to part descriptions.  Also a good idea to include a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code, to show what libraries you are using to read the sensors

Comment: How do you do the capacitive sensing? Libraries? Code? This information is still missing.

Comment: Im not doing it, in code, the hardware is doing it automaticly. I havent figured out how to disable it. I hoped that by not having it in code, that the functionality wouldn't be active, but it would seem to be the opposite

Comment: You wrote: “_Im not doing it, in code, the hardware is doing it automaticly_”. Wrong. This board is based on the ATmega32u4, which does not natively support touch sensing. I _can_ detect touch with the appropriate code/library, but it cannot do it in a hardware-only way.

Comment: Then how do i get functionality of capacitive touch,  if my code doesn't use it. Why isnt it just disabled? I'm here for answers, guys, basing my questions on observations. If i knew already, I wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 1):

`digitalRead(pin)` is the wrong way to read capacitive touch inputs.

In the [file from the example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPlayground/blob/e871c0b23ff6731489045142464f233853ac43cd/examples/mega_demo/CapTouchDemo.h) you linked in [your answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/41446), the reading is made by calling `CircuitPlayground.readCap(pin, num_samples)` and then the returning value is compared to a threshold.

```cpp
const uint16_t TOUCH_THRESHOLD = 300;

...

if (CircuitPlayground.readCap(Fire) >= TOUCH_THRESHOLD) {
   Keyboard.write(KEY_SPACE);
   Serial.println('F');
}
...
```

You can change the sensitivity by changing `TOUCH_THRESHOLD`. You could also add and fiddle with the second argument to change the number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the best method for finding a solution, perhaps, but I was tooling around in the Adafruit_CircuitPalyground repo, and found a macro for the Capacitive touch sensitivity.

The macro is:

```
#define CAP_THRESHOLD 300 // Threshold for a capacitive touch (higher = less sensitive).
```

Located here: 
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPlayground/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CAP_THRESHOLD&type=

I'm reading more, and trying to find the libraries for capacitive touch. There may be a much better solution, but for now defining CAP_THRESHOLD works well enough.